# AC to DC conversion, how to keep the voltage same?

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, voltage-measurement, bridge-rectifier

I have an amplifier board. The maximum input voltage is -40V 0 +40V DC. I have a 30V 0 30V 5 amp transformer. When I read the DC voltage after rectification, it shows around -45V 0 +45V. So what is the easy way to reduce the DC voltage? The board draws high current also.

Comment: Regulator circuits (one per rail) or unwind a few turns on the transformer secondary to get the correct voltage from the start.

Comment: Use emitter follower BJT regulators straight after the bridge and before it connects to the smoothing capacitors. You'll need some heatsinking too but that depends entirely on what type of  signal you are using the amplifier for.

Comment: How high is high current? Because if you're trying to drop 5V, then anything past 500mA is probably going to be too much heat to reasonably dissipate with a simple linear regulator. Unless you go for big transistors and big heatsinks, The kind where the heatsink is large enough to dominate the mass of the equipment.

Comment: get a 24V transformer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could make simple regulators using Darlington transistors and Zener diodes, like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj9dz4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At high current draw the transistors will get hot and need large heat sinks. They will have to drop ~7 V and so at 5 A could dissipate up to 35 W each, assuming your rectified output stays at 45 V. However if that voltage is unloaded the average rectified voltage under load will probably be less, and the power dissipation will be less. For example if  the voltage difference was 2 V at 5 A then power dissipation would be ~10 W.

This circuit has the advantage of making the amplifier supply voltages more stable with lower ripple, but needs several components including possibly bulky heatsinks.

If you just want to lower the voltage with fewest components you could use another mains transformer with low voltage secondary wired in series with the primary winding of the 30 VAC transformer, with the correct phase to 'buck' the mains voltage. For example if the mains is 120 VAC then a transformer with 15 VAC output would reduce it to 105 VAC or 12.5% less, reducing the DC output from 45 V to ~39 V. This transformer can be quite small because it only has to handle the primary current (~2.5 A for a 120 VAC transformer with 30-0-30 VAC 5 A output).

Answer (score 0):

If the current is on the high side all the time (say, min one tenth of max, on both +&-), one costly (outdated/"vintage") option is to add two inductors (? coupled/common core viable?) for a [*choke input filter*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Choke_input_filter).
For 30 V single phase sine input, expect 25-26 V DC.

Comment: As a bonus, you get more power from the same transformer: Transformer utilisation factor .8 vs. .6.